# Mapping Kansas City based on X and Y Coordinates in R

Tags: r, maps

I have a csv file in R that has coordinates of Kansas City, however, the values at these points aren't in any traditional longitude/latitude formatting that I am aware of.  My data looks like this:

```
Tract            X               Y
218.01       2797574          1143595
218.01       2799346          1144802
133.02       2786207           998301
...
```

Is there anyway that I can generate a map from this type of data that will also eventually allow for the visualization of other variables such as population or crime rate?

Comment: They look like projected coordinates.  You'll need to know the exact projection, at which point you can convert them back to lat/lon or re-project them.  The R tools for that are `proj4string` and `spTransform`.

Comment: Thanks.  I am a bit confused as to how I would go about obtain the exact projection.  The strange thing is that I can plot the X and Y points and it comes up with the Kansas City area as a display of points.

Comment: If the data source didn't provide it, your only real option is to try to figure out which projection it is by transforming a known point using a bunch of common projections and see how it goes.

Comment: Can you at least work out what the units of distance are? You know how big Kansas City is, so can you tell if these are exactly metres or feet, for example? If they seem to be nothing like that then I think you should go back to the source and get a shapefile with a proper coordinate system, eg http://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:KC_Census_Tracts1_y8o or some other source.