# Mapping variables based on STFID values

Tags: r

This quest is an extention of a question that I made earlier today but since it's migration to GIS I haven't been able to comment on my older post.  My earlier post is : [Mapping Kansas City based on X and Y Coordinates in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78558/mapping-kansas-city-based-on-x-and-y-coordinates-in-r)

I have found a more specific coordinate system known as STFID.  From what I have researched about STFID the larger the number the more specific of a locale the point equals.  Each STFID contains 15 digits, which I believe is sufficient enough to account for each block in Kansas City, MO.

Is there a way that I can map information in R when using this STFID value?

Comment: What have you tried? You have a better chance of getting an answer if you submit code (it doesn't matter if it doesn't work) and a sample of your data. If your data is proprietary then create something similar - [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is very useful. Do you have just two columns in this CSV file, STFID and a value, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

As a general point `ggplot2` seems to understand shapefiles that contain STFIDs, such as those used in the US Census Tract data. Using [that data for San Francisco](http://goo.gl/B4uwri) I came up with this:

[image: sf]

If your CSV file has two STFID coordinates for each line then you might be able to plot it with a variation on the code below. Until you show us some data it's hard to be sure.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
# source URL for San Francisco zipped shapefile and related:
# http://goo.gl/B4uwri

work.dir <- "your_work_dir" # no trailing slash
mysp <- readOGR(work.dir, layer = "census2000_tracts_nowater")

mydf <- fortify(mysp, region = 'STFID') # convert to data frame for ggplot
mydf$fakedata <- runif(nrow(mydf), 1, 10) # create random data

ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = fakedata, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(colour = "black") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(5970000, 6030000)) + # constrain the scale
    coord_equal() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```